# How manifold-like is Aut(C^n) in the holomorphic category?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

This question is similar to, but not the same as [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26555/are-spaces-of-holomorphic-maps-manifolds). Take the space of automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$ in the holomorphic category, with the compact-open topology. For $n=1$ this is just $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}^*$, but for larger $n$ is very complicated. It clearly contains $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, and translations.

To give a taste of how big $Aut(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is, there is a [theorem](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2001110) that given any two countable dense subsets $X,Y \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, $n >1$, there is a volume preserving automorphism taking $X$ to $Y$. But I have no idea about what this space is like. Is it some sort of infinite dimensional manifold? Analytic space? Does it contain an infinite dimensional Lie group as a (closed) subgroup?

Comment: I don't know what counts as an infinite-dimensional Lie group, but you can make lots of closed subgroups, for example the stabilizer of a point or a line or a function $\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C$. 

Comment: Say a Frechet Lie group. A Banach Lie group might be too much to ask.

Comment: In the algebraic case it's horrifying: not representable for any $n > 1$. Indeed, suppose rep'td by some $G$. Then Grothendieck's functorial criterion for being locally of finite presentation forces $G$ to be loc. of finite type, then smooth (by Cartier), so $G^0$ is a *finite type* connected smooth group variety.  This forces the points of $G^0$ to act by automorphisms represented by polynomials of *bounded* degree, which is absurd for $n > 1$ since for two distinct variables $(x,y)$ can use $(x,y) \mapsto (x + t y^n, y)$ to get a connected family of auts joining id to arb. big degree.

Answer (score 5):

It is a group generated by flows of holomorphic vector fields. Its Lie algebra is a set of all holomorphic vector fields. As I can for now remember there were a computation of its group of cohomologies (by Feigin and Fuchs: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=3301&option_lang=eng

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=intf&paperid=93&option_lang=eng
)

Maybe this book can help if you have no translation of these articles from Russian:
Fuks D.B.   Cohomology of infinite-dimensional Lie algebras, Consultants Bureau, 1986

I think that you have much to learn from this book.

Also there is an article: http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.3398 - it may be rather useful

Comment: But you can easily write down two polynomial vector fields that have global flows, and whose sum does not.

Comment: @Tom: Maybe. I really don't know if it so.